# Finding the volume of a solid bounded by curves and a line using the shell method

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the volume of a solid bounded by the curves y= x^2, y= 2-x and the line x=0 for any x value that is greater than or equal to 0 by using the shell method. My main problem is finding my limits of integration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are revolving this area around the $x$ axis the limits of integration are from $y = 0$ to $y = 2$ (the $y$ intercept of $y = 2-x$). If this area is revolved around the $y$ axis, then the limits of integration are from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$ (the intersection of $y = x^2$ and $y = 2-x$).